# Drawing Issues in OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

In my app, I have a red square (actually two triangles) that gets drawn onto the screen. However, if the user taps on the screen or moves their finger around, the drawing gets messed up and causes the square to start drawing in what seems to be random patterns. Any idea why this is happening? Code:

```
Triangle3D  *triangles = malloc(sizeof(Triangle3D) * 2);
triangles[0].v1 = Vertex3DMake(x, y, -3.0);
triangles[0].v2 = Vertex3DMake(x+1.0, y-1.0, -3.0);
triangles[0].v3 = Vertex3DMake(x-1.0, y-1.0, -3.0);
triangles[1].v1 = Vertex3DMake(x-1.0, y-1.0, -3.0);
triangles[1].v2 = Vertex3DMake(x+1.0, y-1.0, -3.0);
triangles[1].v3 = Vertex3DMake(x, y-2.0, -3.0);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, triangles);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 18);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glClearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Triangle Strip's vetcies should be arranged like this graph.
[image: TRIANGLE_STRIP]

The other forms.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thats it! Thanks. Out of curiosity, how do you post pictures in an answer?

Comment: When you post answer, there is an icon in the toolbar, which can insert image url.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're setting `triangles[1].v1` 3 times rather than setting `triangles[1].v1, v2, & v3`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but oddly that wasn't the problem. I changed it but my program still behaved the same way.